# ColorChooserWidget GTK 3.0 Python

Tags: python, gtk3

Make ColorChooserWidget in GTK 3.0 stretch to fill all available space

I've trying to stretch colorchooserwidget to fits all available space in my screen panel

```
self.color_chooser = Gtk.ColorChooserWidget()
self.color_chooser.set_vexpand(True)
self.color_chooser.set_hexpand(True)
self.color_chooser.set_valign(Gtk.Align.FILL)
self.color_chooser.set_halign(Gtk.Align.FILL)
cc_box = Gtk.Box()
cc_box.set_vexpand(True)
cc_box.set_hexpand(True)
cc_box.set_valign(Gtk.Align.FILL)
cc_box.set_halign(Gtk.Align.FILL)
cc_box.pack_start(self.color_chooser, True, True, 0)
self.content.add(cc_box)
```

where self.content is also a box that holds all the available space of the screem.
Also, I've tried to wrap colorchooserwidget in a grid or another box or pass it to self.content directly without wrapping, but anyway colorchooserwidget stays the same size and not gets all available space (not stretches to fill all available spase). Am I right that widget does not have built-in support for automatic stretching or filling the available space? Is there any way to achieve that?